# "How to fix "Image not uploading into firebase-storage using Picasso library"

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, picasso

I'm trying to make a profile activity where user's data will be shown and also user can edit their data also. Everything works fine. There is no error showing in the code but when i'm trying to upload an image using camera or gallery. It's not uploading in the firebase storage. Also no "Toast" message shows. I'm fully stucked in this problem. How to solve this problem? The following code is given below:

```
package com.example.muthomap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    //views
    ImageView profilephoto;
    private TextView pname,pemail,pphone;
    private FloatingActionButton medit;

    //Instance of FirebaseAuth
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    //progress Dialog
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //permissions constants
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE=200;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE=300;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=400;


    //arrays of permissions to be requested
    String cameraPermissions[];
    String storagePermissions[];

    //uri of picked image
    Uri image_uri;

    //to check either profile or cover photo
    String profileOrCoverPhoto;

    //storage
    StorageReference storageReference;

    //path where imagees of profile and cover will  be stored
    String storagePath = "Users_Profile_Cover_Imgs/";

    public Profile(){


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);



        profilephoto= findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        pname= findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        pemail= findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        pphone= findViewById(R.id.profile_mobile);
        medit= findViewById(R.id.edit);

        //Initialize the FirebaseAuth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference= firebaseDatabase.getReference("user").child("customers");
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(storagePath);

        //intitalize arrays of permissions
        cameraPermissions= new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermissions= new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating User.....");

        /*We need to get current signed in users email,name,phone etc. And we retrive user
        detail using email.*/
        /* by using OrderByChild query we will show the detail from a node whose
        key named email has value equal to currently signed in email.
        It will search all nodes, where the key matches it will get it's detail.
         */
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
       query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               //check until getting required data
               for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   //get data
                   String name = "" + ds.child("name").getValue();
                   String email = "" + ds.child("email").getValue();
                   String phone = "" + ds.child("phone").getValue();
                   String image = "" + ds.child("image").getValue();

                   //set data
                   pname.setText(name);
                   pemail.setText(email);
                   pphone.setText(phone);
                   try {
                       Picasso.get().load(image).resize(50, 50)
                               .centerCrop().into(profilephoto);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       //if there is any exceptions while getting image then set defaults
                       Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_default_face).into(profilephoto);
                   }
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });

        //handleing floating Button
             medit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShowEditProfileDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission(){
        /*check if storage permission is enebled or not
        return true if enebled
        return false if not
         */
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestStoragePermission(){
        //request runtime storage permission
        requestPermissions(storagePermissions,STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission(){
        /*check if storage permission is enebled or not
        return true if enebled
        return false if not
         */
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }
    private void requestCameraPermission(){
        //request runtime camera permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(cameraPermissions,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }



    private void ShowEditProfileDialog() {
        /*show dialog of options
               *1. Upload Photo
               *2. Edit Name
               *3. Edit phone
         */

        //options ro show in Dialog

        String options[ ] = {"Upload Photo","Edit Name","Edit phone"};

        //alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //title
        builder.setTitle("Choose Actions");

        //set items
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (which == 0){
                    //Edit Profile picture clicked
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Profile Picture");
                    profileOrCoverPhoto = "image";
                    showImagePicDialog();
                }
                else if (which == 1){
                    //Edit Name clicked
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Name");
                    showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("name");
                }
                else if (which == 2){
                    //Edit Phone clicked
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Phone Number");
                    showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("phone");
                }

            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void showNamePhoneUpdateDialog(final String key) {

        //custom dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(Profile.this);
        builder.setTitle("Update "+ key);
        //set layout of dialog
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        //add edit text
        final EditText editText = new EditText(Profile.this);
        editText.setHint("Enter "+key);
        linearLayout.addView(editText);

        builder.setView(linearLayout);
        //add button to update
        builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //input text
                String val = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                //validate if user has entered somethig or not
                if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(val))){
                    progressDialog.show();
                    HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();
                    results.put(key, val);

                    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, ""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Please Enter ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        //add button to cancel
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        //create and show dialog
        builder.create().show();

    }

    private void showImagePicDialog() {

        //options containing options Camera and Gallery

        String options[ ] = {"Camera","Gallery"};

        //alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //title
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");

        //set items
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (which == 0){
                   //Camera Clicked

                    if (!checkCameraPermission()){
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                    else {
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                }
                else if (which == 1){
                    //Gallery Picked

                    if (!checkStoragePermission()){
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestStoragePermission();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                }


            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       /*This method called when user press Allow or Deny from permission request dialog
       here we will handle permissions cases (allowed or denied)
        */

       switch (requestCode){
           case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{
               //picking from camera, first check if camera and storage permission allowed or not
               if (grantResults.length>0){
                   boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                   boolean writeStorageAccepted= grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                   if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted){
                       //permission enebled
                       pickFromCamera();
                   }
                   else {
                       Toast.makeText(this,  "Please eneble Camera and Storage permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           }
           break;

           case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{
               //picking from storage, first check if storage permission allowed or not
               if (grantResults.length >0 ){
                   boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                   if (writeStorageAccepted){
                       //permission enebled
                       pickFromGallery();
                   }
                   else {
                       Toast.makeText(this,  "Please eneble Storage permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

            }

       }
       break;

    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //This method will be called after picking image from Camera or Gallery
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if (resultCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE){
                //image is picked from gallery , get uri of image
                image_uri = data.getData();
                uploadProfilePhoto(image_uri);

            }

            if (resultCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
                //image is picked from Camera, get uri
                uploadProfilePhoto(image_uri);

            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    private void uploadProfilePhoto(Uri uri) {
        //show progress
        progressDialog.show();

        /*The parameter "image_uri" contains the uri of image picked either from camera or gallery
         *Will use UID of the currently signed in user as name of the image so ther will be only one image
         * profile and one image for cover for each user */

        //path and name of image to be stored in firebase storage
        String filePathAndName = storagePath+ ""+ profileOrCoverPhoto +"_"+  user.getUid();
        StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(filePathAndName);
        storageReference2nd.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask=taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                //check if uploading is successfull
                if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                    //image uploaded
                    //add url in user's database
                    HashMap<String,Object> results = new HashMap<>();

                    results.put(profileOrCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());
                    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    //url in database of user is added successfully
                                    //dismiss progress bar
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Image Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Error Updating Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                }
                else {
                    //error
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Some Error Occurd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


    }

    private void pickFromCamera() {

        //Intent of picking image from device camera
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp Pic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Description");

        //put image uri
        image_uri=Profile.this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

        //intent to open camera
        Intent cameraIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    private void pickFromGallery() {

        //pick from gallery
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    }
```

---

Logcat: Logcat log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NqTU.jpg

Comment: Please do not post your full code. Just give us the parts necessary. And add the logcat error messages as well. From the first sight, I think you might have been missing an `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I've taken the INTERNET permission properly.

Comment: Add your logcat error in your post please.

Comment: Uploaded log image.

Comment: Okay i've solved the problem. The problem was in code.